# first-child:first-letter not working in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, css, blogger, css-selectors

The URL is http://crispylogs.com/writing-high-quality-posts-to-increase-traffic-top-20-tips/

I am trying to add an effect, like a magazine's "drop-cap," but it's not working for me, and I don't know why.

The following is the CSS code I have used:

```
.single .entry p:first-child:first-letter {  
    float: left;  
    color: #903;  
    font-size: 47px;  
    line-height: 40px;  
    padding-top: 0px;  
    padding-right: 8px;  
    padding-left: 3px;  
    font-family: Georgia;  
}
```

Comment: What's your (relevant) HTML? Note: I have removed the `pre` element, which I'm assuming was a formatting attempt here, rather than a reproduction from your CSS.

Comment: @DavidThomas I am trying to use it in my WordPress blog.

Comment: So? It still generates HTML which the browser constructs into a DOM. What (relevant) HTML does the browser receive?

Comment: @DavidThomas I am really beginner to it, I don't know what are you trying to say. Please check out the link and help me resolve my problem.. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your p tag is not first child. That is the problem

try first-of-type

Comment: your first child is a DIV

Comment: Be aware that first-of-type is IE9 +

Comment: If it is so, then why we are using p:first-child?? what does it mean?? Doesn't it mean the very first-child of the paragraph tag??

Comment: @Naveed No, `p:first-child` means "a `p` tag that _is_ the first child of its parent". `p > *:first-child` would be the "first child of a `p` tag"

Comment: @BrianNorth Nice explanation, now i get it. thank alot..!! as you said that use first-of-type i have used and it resolved my problem but i am getting error in other post, can u help?? the link is http://crispylogs.com/missing-malaysian-airlines-plane-the-clues-and-claims/

Answer (score 0):

that is not CSS

remove the `<pre> </pre>`

that should help

Comment: By me, rather than the OP; so it *might* have been present, but I think it's more likely to be a formatting snafu *here* while trying to present the code as code.

Comment: @Johansrk I am not getting you, what are you trying to say??

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use your styles to create the effect you want: http://jsfiddle.net/uEkqU/

Perhaps you're running into a specificity issue? Try the following:

```
.post .entry p:first-child:first-letter {  
    float: left;  
    color: #903;  
    font-size: 47px;  
    line-height: 40px;  
    padding-top: 0px;  
    padding-right: 8px;  
    padding-left: 3px;  
    font-family: Georgia;  
}
```